# What does the -f parameter do in the tar command

Tags: tar

When using `tar` I always include `-f` in the parameters but I have no idea why.

I looked up the man and it said;

```
-f, --file [HOSTNAME:]F

use archive file or device F (default
"-", meaning stdin/stdout)
```

But to be honest I have no idea what that means.  Can anyone shed any light on it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `-f` option tells `tar` that the next argument is the file name of the archive, or standard output if it is `-`.

Comment: Ah, cheers! I presumed that the file name would have to appear next anyway so this -f was doing something more special!

Comment: @Toby:  I suspect this is for historical reasons.  "tar" is short for "tape archive", and presumably the original versions didn't envision people using disk files for archives all that often.

Answer (score 9):

Quite simple. If you omit the `-f` parameter, output is passed to stdout:

```
gammy@denice:/tmp/demo$ tar -c a b c
a0000644000175000017500000000000011435437117010223 0ustar  gammygammyb0000644000175000017500000000000011435437117010224 0ustar  gammygammyc0000644000175000017500000000000011435437117010225 0ustar  gammygammygammy@denice:/tmp/demo$ ls
a  b  c
gammy@denice:/tmp/demo$
```

...what a mess!

The `-f`-parameter (as you quoted) expects a filename (and optionally a hostname), hence the first argument after it is the output filename:

```
gammy@denice:/tmp/demo$ tar -cf output.tar a b c
gammy@denice:/tmp/demo$ ls
a  b  c  output.tar
gammy@denice:/tmp/demo$
```

Comment: > *If you oppress the -f parameter, output is passed to stdout*.

This is true with GNU tar, but I remember that on Solaris the default was a tape device (`/dev/rmt0` or something like this).

Comment: *omit (not "oppress")

Comment: Even GNU `tar` honours the no-longer-documented `TAPE` variable. For example, try `TAPE=/tmp/tape.tar tar cv /etc/h*` and then `ls -l /tmp/tape.tar`.

Answer (score 2):

It lets you specify the file or device you're going to be working with. Either creating, updating or extracting things from it depending on other supplied flags.
For example:

```
# Create a tar file with the contents of somepath/
tar -cvf filename.tar somepath/

# Extract the tar file.
tar -xvf filename.tar
```